# How to set time_ranges for Ad Report Stats?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/

Based on the documentation

time_ranges Array of timestamp objects {time_start, time_stop} or date objects {day, month, year}.

So in the Graph API Explorer, I am setting the time_ranges value as

```
time_ranges=[{"day_start":{"day":1,"month":11,"year":2013}},{"day_stop":{"day":10,"month":11,"year":2013}}]
```

This returns me an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Please set time_start and time_stop or day_start and day_stop.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I have removed other part of the above URL for brevity. I have tried with date_preset value and the report returns data.

Thanks.

EDIT: The complete URL (sans the valid account id)

> > https://graph.facebook.com/act_12345/reportstats?data_columns=["account_id","account_name","campaign_id","campaign_name","impressions","clicks","spend"]&time_ranges=["{'day_start':{'day':1,'month':11,'year':2013}}","{'day_stop':{'day':10,'month':11,'year':2013}}"]

Comment: At the time I had ended up using time_interval with Unix timestamps. Like https://graph.facebook.com/act_1234567/reportstats?data_columns=["account_id","account_name","campaign_id","campaign_name"]&time_interval={'time_start':1393142400,'time_stop':1393315200}&time_increment=1

I haven't verified whether the answers that were posted after @Tommy Crush's work or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had (have!) an identical issue.

I worked around it by using `time_start` and `time_stop` instead of `day_start` and `day_stop`. Stupid, I know... but it's what worked for me.

So to get 1-day's worth of data (the 19th of Nov for example):

```
 &time_ranges=["{'time_start': '2013-11-19','time_stop':'2013-11-20'}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, the example appears to be an array of strings that are json objects. So try changing this line:

```
time_ranges=[{"day_start":{"day":1,"month":11,"year":2013}},{"day_stop":{"day":10,"month":11,"year":2013}}]
```

to this:

```
time_ranges=["{'day_start':{'day':1,'month':11,'year':2013}}","{'day_stop':{'day':10,'month':11,'year':2013}}"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Tommy for checking this. But I still get the same error. I've modified my post with the complete URL, in case something else you see there is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try using:

```
time_ranges=["{'day_start':{'day':1,'month':11,'year':2013}, 'day_stop':{'day':10,'month':11,'year':2013}}"]
```

instead of:

```
time_ranges=["{'day_start':{'day':1,'month':11,'year':2013}}","{'day_stop':{'day':10,'month':11,'year':2013}}"]
```

Complete URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/act_12345/reportstats?data_columns=["account_id","account_name","campaign_id","campaign_name","impressions","clicks","spend"]&time_ranges=["{'day_start':{'day':1,'month':11,'year':2013}, 'day_stop':{'day':10,'month':11,'year':2013}}"]
```

I opened a documentation issue at https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1423346704577387/